# Query to arrange rows horizontally

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot

I have 2 tables which I need to join and produce a third table with columns arranged horizontally. The tables are as follows:
[image]

I need the output 2 from `table1` and `table2`.

I did some research and found that I need to use `PIVOT`. I wrote some query also. My query is

```
SELECT  * FROM (
  SELECT 
  CONVERT(CHAR(4), table_2.Date, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), table_2.Date, 120) as    RegistrationDate,  
  table_1.PDESC as ProductDescription from table_2 
  left outer join table_1 on table_1.PID = table_2.PID
) 
tableT
PIVOT (count(ProductDescription) FOR RegistrationDate
IN ([Jan 2009],[Feb 2009],[Mar 2009],[Apr 2009],[May 2009],[Jun 2009])) AS pvt
```

But this query is not working! I have attached the SQL script also to create the tables.

I have uploaded the script to [here](http://www.ziddu.com/download/22120435/script.txt.html) .

Comment: Post your script to sqlfiddle.com instead of that NSFW site

Comment: You should never give a *download* link on a [so] question, especially not to a file-sharing site. Code should preferably be contained in the question itself, if it's too long, you should probably try to construct a shorter example, if this is not possible, one should link to a site (preferably well-known with a decent reputation) where the code appears and doesn't need to be downloaded. If the download link you provided has code identical to the code in the question, the link should be removed.

Comment: Since you are selecting from `table_2` and joining to `table_1`, and assuming `table_2.PID` is a foreign key to `table_1.PID` you should change your join to an `INNER` join, since no record can exist in `table_2` that doesn't exist in `table_1`. Or change so you are selecting from table_1 and left joining to `table_2` if you want products to show in the results even if there are no records in `table_2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to both `count` and display the `ProductDescription`. If you want to display the `ProductDescription` then there are a few different ways that you can do this.

Instead of applying the `count` to the `ProductDescription`, you can `count` the `PID` column:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM 
(
  SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(4), t2.Date, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), t2.Date, 120) as RegistrationDate,  
    t1.ProductDesc as ProductDescription,
    t1.PID
  from table_2 t2
  left outer join table_1 t1
    on t1.PID = t2.PID
) tableT
PIVOT 
(
  count(PID) FOR RegistrationDate
  IN ([Jan 2009],[Feb 2009],[Mar 2009],[Apr 2009],[May 2009],[Jun 2009])
) AS pvt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2cb3/9).

Or you can create a second column in the subquery to return the `ProductDescription` twice. One column will be used in the count and the second will be used in the final display:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM 
(
  SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(4), t2.Date, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), t2.Date, 120) as RegistrationDate,  
    t1.ProductDesc as ProductDescription,
    t1.ProductDesc as Product
  from table_2 t2
  left outer join table_1 t1
    on t1.PID = t2.PID
) tableT
PIVOT 
(
  count(ProductDescription) FOR RegistrationDate
  IN ([Jan 2009],[Feb 2009],[Mar 2009],[Apr 2009],[May 2009],[Jun 2009])
) AS pvt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2cb3/10)